# conditional expectation simplification

Tags: econometrics

[image]

On the right hand of the expression above, why could we move the condition  ' |X '   to the numerator without making any other changes?

Answer (score 4):

If the value of $X$ is known, $X_i-\bar{X}$ and $(X_i-\bar{X})^2$ are known quantities, and so the only random variables that are unknown are the $U_i$.  More simply, remember that $E[Y\mid X]$ is a *function of* $X$, not of $Y$ as one might think, and $E[f(X)Y\mid X]$ equals $f(X)E[Y\mid X]$, which is also a function of $X$ and not of $Y$.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you so much.

Comment: @VicTu If this answered your question, please select it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $\mathbb E[\cdot|X]$ is just a notation for the conditional expectation that associates to a random variable $Z$ the random variable $\mathbb E[Z|X]$ as the closest function of $X$, in the sense  of the least square solution
$$f^* = \arg \min_f \mathbb E[(Z-f(X))^2]$$
i.e. $f^*(X)=\mathbb E[Z|X]$. The notation $|X$ thus does not have a meaning by itself and cannot be "moved" around the expectation argument. In other words, [$Y|X$ does not exist](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/507236/f-y-vert-x-x-vs-fy-vert-x-x).