# What's the difference between Y|X and Y|X=x

Tags: probability, random-variable, conditional-probability

Suppose that Y and X are two random variables.

What is the difference between $Y|X$ and $Y|X=x$?

Comment: Neither are defined as such. When writing $\mathbb E[Y|X]$ this is understood as a random variable that is a (deterministic) transform of the random variable $X$. When writing $\mathbb E[Y|X=x]$ this is understood as the realisation of the above rv when the realisation of $X$ is $x$.

Comment: If neither are defined as such then how can we say that $Y|X=x\sim \mathcal{N}(5x,\,\sigma^{2})\,$. Am I missing something?

Comment: This means that the $Y$ random variable, conditioned on the realization $x$ of the random variable $X$ is normally distributed with mean $5x$ and standard deviation $\sigma$.

Comment: So $Y|X=x$ is defined as a conditional probability distribution conditional on the realization of the random variable $X$. Also, as Xi'an correctly points out $E[Y|X] $ is also a random variable and $E[Y|X=x] $ is a function of $X$. My question is how $Y|X$ is defined?

Comment: $Y|X$ as such does not have a meaning. $Y$ is a random variable and $(X,Y)$ is a pair of random variables.

Comment: See also the discussion on this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/507236/7224